# Python: Define Function to contain list of attributes as variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the following class to format integers and string values into a desired format as shown below:

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

print(bcolors.WARNING + "Sample Warning Text. Continue?" + bcolors.ENDC)
```

However, my goal is to have a function such as:

```
color_format(input,format)
```

which would essentially make the use of formatting easier.

Is there an option to define an array of possible option in a function? E.g.

```
def color_format(input, format)
         format = [
                   HEADER = '\033[95m',
                   OKBLUE = '\033[94m',
                   OKGREEN = '\033[92m',
                   WARNING = '\033[93m',
                   FAIL = '\033[91m',
                   ENDC = '\033[0m',
                   BOLD = '\033[1m',
                   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
                   ]
          print(format + input + ENDC='\033[0m')
```

```
color_format("This is a bold text",BOLD)
```

~**This is a bold text**

I'd appreciate your help alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `dict` with mapping from names to values.

```py
FORMATS = {
    'HEADER': '\033[95m',
    'OKBLUE': '\033[94m',
    'OKGREEN': '\033[92m',
    'WARNING': '\033[93m',
    'FAIL': '\033[91m',
    'ENDC': '\033[0m',
    'BOLD': '\033[1m',
    'UNDERLINE': '\033[4m'
}

def color_format(text, format):
    try:
        formatted = FORMATS[format] + text + FORMATS['ENDC']
    except KeyError:
        print('Invalid format! Possible values are: ', FORMATS.keys())
    else:
        print(formatted)
```